# react-datepicker gives wrong values

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am building an application and I am using react-datepicker however i have a strange behavior of the component. The selected date shows wrong format.
Here is what i am using:

```
this.state={
   selectedDate: moment().format(),
}
```

and

```
<DatePicker selected={this.state.selectedDate}/>
```

The problem is that the component shows the below value:
`"52//02/2019/"`.

It seems like the component is counting how many days have passed till the current date in the year.
I've also tried `moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY')` with no luck.
any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: are you looking for a solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f7bzqs ?

Comment: @Jayavel using the dateformat from your code showed the correct format but now i cannot change the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i am posting this as an answer to show what  worked for me. I believe this is too big to be a comment.

So I set:

```
this.state={selectedDate:moment().format()}
```

and in the component i used:

```
<DatePicker selected={this.state.selectedDate} 
   dateFormat={moment(this.state.selectedDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}/>
```

This way i was able to change the selected date and get the current date value instead of the days count.
However I am still not sure of how great this solution is. At least it works for me for now.
Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I used moment().format('DD MM YYYY') means inside without any '/' in between. Try below code:

```
    this.state = {
        startDate: moment().format('DD MM YYYY')
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to format like that (2 these format are same each other):

```
value ={moment(this.state.startDay).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}
format="DD/MM/YYYY"
```

Answer (score 0):

From 2.0.0 React-datepicker dropped moment.js and started using dateFns.

What you need to do is remove moment.js and provide native Date object as a selected prop, and custom formatting string as a fomat prop.

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
    />
  );
};
```